# Ubuntu cluster throwing java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: java, ubuntu, network-programming

my **/etc/hosts** file looks something like this

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0     ip6-localnet
ff00::0     ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1     ip6-allnodes
ff02::2     ip6-allrouters
#127.0.1.1       server3
x.y.z.x0 server1
x.y.z.x1 server2
x.y.z.x2 server3
x.x.z.x3 server4
```

But when I try to run simple java code using **MPJExpress**, I find the following exception

***abraham@myserver:~/project$ mpjboot machines*** (The content of the machines file is same as that of /etc/hosts)

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: ip6-localnet
    at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:867)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1246)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1197)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1128)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1064)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1014)
    at runtime.starter.PortScan.main(PortScan.java:41)
mpjboot found port 10000 busy on ip6-localnet machine. There are two possibilities:
    (1) The daemon might already be running...
    (2) If the daemon is not running, then set a different port by modifying the wrapper.app.parameter.2 property in the /home/hduser/
```

I have tried changing the port number as suggested by the error message but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Here is my platform information:
 **Ubuntu Linaro 12.08 running on armv7l**

Comment: The stack trace should give you a hint.  You have asked the IPV4 resolver to look up an IPV6 address.  That won't work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @JimGarrison But I am getting the error as I tried compiling it with  -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true option. Without that option, the error is the same except the first line which becomes "at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)". Ofcourse, the line number of the errors also change.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because of incorrect machines file format. Machines file should contain either the ip address of machines or there names (which are mapped to ip-address in hosts file).

According to given host file, machines file should be either like this

```
server1
server2
server3
server4
```

Or

```
x.y.z.x0
x.y.z.x1
x.y.z.x2
x.x.z.x3
```